# How to add/remove object in Recyclerview using Arraylist in Android?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I am developing a demo music player app.

For creating Playlists, i am using a recylcerview in which clicking on item add the items to arraylist and alternative click remove the item from the arraylist.

I added the items to arraylist successfully but i am unsuccessful in removing the particular index on alternative click.

```
  ArrayList<PlayList> playListsSongs;

    holder.viewForeground.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (v.getTag() == null || v.getTag().equals("NotSelected")) {

                        playListsSongs.add(new PlayList(songs.getSong_id(), songs.getSong_path()));
                        v.setTag("Selected");
                    } else {

// NEEDS TO REMOVE THE OBJECT ADDED TO LIST HERE

                     playListsSongs.remove(position);
                        v.setTag("NotSelected");
                    }
                }
            });
```

I checked with multiple answers but i am unsuccessful. So, kindly give me a hint so that i can able to learn.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: after remove item from arraylist you have to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

After changing data in your list you need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in order to update adapter data.

Answer (score 0):

After each list modification you should notify the adapter.

```
adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)
```

to notify the deletion

Answer (score 0):

Setting tag is the problem in my code.  After tagging the position to the recyclerview item, my code is working.

```
if (holder.viewForeground.getTag() == null) {
                    playListsSongs.add(new PlayList(songs.getSong_id(), songs.getSong_path()));
                    holder.viewForeground.setTag(position);

                } else {
                    playListsSongs.remove(holder.viewForeground.getTag());
                    holder.viewForeground.setTag(null);

                }
```

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use this in onclick to remove

```
notifyItemRemoved(position);
               notifyItemRangeChanged(position,playListsSongs.size());
           notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Did this help ?